# When to use a predicate over passing a CoreData object via the prepare method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have an iOS app that I am currently building. I'm using CoreData for the first time and have a question in regards to passing data from one ViewController to the next. Right now I have a tableview set up in VCa, and when I tap a cell I want to get the details of that object (Person) in VCb. I have been thinking of doing this in 2 different ways.

1. Pass a reference of the Persons name in the prepage function. And over in VCb use a predicate to fetch that person back out of CoreData. Is using another fetch request the correct solution here. There will not be a ton of data in this app, so I don't think it would be very taxing on the system to do another request, but I'm new to CoreData.
2. Capture the data object in VCa and pass that object over to VCb via the prepare function. This would eliminate me having to do another fetch request in VCb but seems like I could be limiting myself for future expansions.

Again, I'm new to CoreData and just wanted some thoughts on which method of thinking is better and why.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever fetch an object *that you have already fetched*. In your case #1 you already have the object that you need, but you'd go ahead and fetch it again for no good reason. It might not be "very taxing" in your case but that just means you're probably not duplicating a lot of work for no reason *yet*, but it's still a bad design. And anyway-- this is an entity representing a person. Are you certain that there would never, ever be more than one person with the same name?

Your second idea is the better one here.

Comment: Thanks Tom, no there will never be 2 people with the same name, I check for that when the person is created.